# Fill empty cells with value of other columns not modifying original dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame`

```
Company Name        | Person Name  | Phone number
General Electric    | John Doe     | 
Ford                |              | 123 456 789
```

I want to fill empty names with the company name

```
Company Name        | Person Name  | Phone number
General Electric    | John Doe     | 
Ford                | Ford         | 123 456 789
```

I could write
`df.loc[df["Person Name"].isna(),'Person Name'] = df["Company Name"]`
but it would modify the original DataFrame.

`df.copy().loc[df["Person Name"].isna(),'Person Name'] = df["Company Name"]` should do the trick, but is there a more elegant way to do it, without using `copy()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `fillna` to fill the missing values in `Person Name` with the values from `Company Name`:

```
df.fillna(df['Company Name'].to_frame('Person Name'))
```

---

```
       Company Name Person Name
0  General Electric    John Doe
1              Ford        Ford
```

Comment: What if I have other columns with na which I dont want to fill ? I'll update the question

Comment: This will only fill the `NaN` values in `Person Name` column.

Answer (score 1):

When you sub set the df from original dataframe add `copy`

```
df = or_df[somecondition].copy()
```

Then `fillna` with

```
df['Person Name'].fillna(df["Company Name"],inplace=True)
```